# How to run methods from another class

Tags: java, class, methods

I am new to Java coding.
I want to know how to run methods from another class without using the extends or implements functions.

I have two questions on this subject.

For organization reasons I have set-up a subclass under a main class which has my run loop. How can I run methods from the subclass in my loop? The main class isn't recognizing the methods of the subclass if they are proclaimed regularly (if(subclassmethodname()==1);).

Also, is there anyway for me to run nonstatic methods from another class (in a totally different file) without using extends or implements?

(I have tried extends and the program I am using to run my script doesn't seem to allow the script to be ran for whatever reason). 
the "(classname).class" menu in Eclipse seems to have a lot of options but I am not sure what to do with them to accomplish my goal...

Comment: Java or Javascript, they are different languages, i assume Java as you mention .class files and eclipse

Comment: Instantiate objects from classes.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html

Comment: When asking for help with code, show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an instance of your subclass then call the method you want.

```
class Child{

public void sayHello(){
System.out.println("hello"); 
}
}
```

from inside parent:

```
Child myChild = new Child(); 
myChild.sayHello();
```

Comment: you have forgot about `out`! `System.out.println("HI Buddy")` :D